# show progress of the background task on a pop-up windows in windows form application using C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating some files from xml data in the background using

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => xmlconvert(xx, yy));
```

Now, the question is how to show the progress of this method using a StatusStrip control with some message and the progress or at least just a scrolling animation for the progress. I don't just have any idea how would it work.

Update:
First of all, this method 'xmlconvert(xx, yy)' has four different forms depends on the condition user selects at runtime.
In the main form of my application user can select from different conditions to process on the data. Then finally when user click on the Button 'Create' all these conditions are being checked and a suitable method will be called within that button click event. I need to show the progress of this method which is being invoked at runtime.

```
private void btnCreateRelease_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Checks set of conditions

      if(cond 1)
      {
          xmlconvert_1();
      }
      else if (cond2)
      {
          xmlconvert_2();
      }
      else if (cond3)
      {
          xmlconvert_3();
      }
      else if (cond4)
      {
          xmlconvert_4();
      }
}
```

I want to show progress of one of these methods which will be invoked at runtime depends on the condition.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should use BackgroundWorker class for this.

Comment: If you don't need to report progress, I've added shorter approach.

Comment: @Giedrius: It worked, but still I would like to learn this in more details, like a proper progress of how much work is done in the background as well as BackgroundWorker. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BackgroundWorker for this, and it's pretty simple, too. Here's a sample to get you going:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your work in here.
        xmlconvert(xx, yy);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

And here's the link to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

To get it to work in your scenario, I would suggest you add a Progress bar to your StatusStrip control and update it from within the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: thank you so much, it is exactly what I want to do. However, again sorry to ask this but when I do it on one progress everything works. I forgot to mention before. I am calling my method xmlconvert(xx, yy); which has four different forms with minor differences and one of them is being invoked on a button click event depends on the conditions given by the user. So, I am again confused How can I use this for that button click event?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Do you have a main form with a Button, and then want to Start the BackgroundWorker in a new form, when the button is clicked?

Comment: I am so terribly sorry for the confusion again.
I have a main form with so much other code. Initially, user calls data from database API in xml format, then gives some different conditions to process on data, finally when he/she clicks on the create button, a desired method which fits to the user conditions is invoked. Here, I need to show the progress of that method only which will be called after the button is clicked.

Comment: No need to apologise. I will update my answer based on the update :-)

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help. In between, I will try to play around with it and try to learn more and something new. This is an amazing feeling of learning new stuff each time when I face problems.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem after reading the documentation on backgroundWorker.
I just had to invoke it in my button click event just after a desired  method is being invoked.

`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => xmlconvert_1();`
`backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish just to show, that your app is not hang may help following approach:

```
public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static void RunWithMargueProgress(this Action action)
    {           
        var progressForm = new ProgressForm();

        progressForm.Show();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(action)
            .ContinueWith(t =>
                              {
                                  progressForm.Close();
                                  progressForm.Dispose();
                              }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());            
    }
}
```

Where `ProgressForm` would be a simple form with `ProgressBar`, that is set to `Marquee` style. If you have idea, how it is progressing, it is better to show progress for user and use `BackgroundWorker`.

As long as it's parameter is `Action`, it is easily reusable.

Usage would be:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action action = () => Thread.Sleep(5000);
    action.RunWithMargueProgress();          
}
```

If you have control in status strip, that you wish to animate, you can do it like this:

```
public static void RunWithMargueProgress(this Action action, ToolStripProgressBar progressBar)
{
    progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;            
    progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(action)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
                           {
                               progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
                               progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;                                      
                           }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Usage would be pretty much the same:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action action = () => Thread.Sleep(5000);
    action.RunWithMargueProgress(ToolStripProgressBar);          
}
```

Comment: It is working pretty well. thanks for such a nice approach. I just cahnged one part where we invoke it. as below.

`Action action = () => xmlconvert_1();`
`RunWithMargueProgress(action, toolStripProgressBar);`